# How to delete data from linkedserver table using where condition from local server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two database for synchronize, i want to delete data from hosted database table not local database table..my table name is global

i am using sql server 2008R2

thank you in advance for your help

```
delete [sql5025.site4now.net].DB_9BDE_alfaSuit.dbo.[global] where no not in (select no from [global])
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add alias of local database.

```
delete [sql5025.site4now.net].DB_9BDE_alfaSuit.dbo.[global] where no not in 
(select no from DB_9BDE_alfaSuit.dbo.[global])
```

This will return data from linked server

```
select * from [sql5025.site4now.net].DB_9BDE_alfaSuit.dbo.[global]
```

This will return data from local server

```
select * from DB_9BDE_alfaSuit.dbo.[global]
```

Comment: the issue is taking a long time to delete the table. the query is working. when i using select instead of delete. it is working fine